# How to store 3 decimal places with MySQL

Tags: mysql, double, decimal-point

I have a field in my database table, type of: `double`

How can I store a value like this: ***0,001*** in it?

I've already tried, but it's truncated into **0,00**.

Comment: If the data type is `double` (without any size parameters), then truncation at this level of precision is almost certainly occurring at the presentation layer, rather than in the database itself; how are you retrieving and displaying the value to determine that it has been truncated?

Comment: @eggyal - with simple SELECT FROM, without FORMAT statement. Other answers helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the number of decimal places as part of the table definition: `colname double(4,3)` allows one digit before the decimal and three digits after.